# How to do scp in R?

Tags: r, linux, ssh, copy, scp

I was wondering whether `scp` like:

```
scp localmachine/path_to_the_file username@server_ip:/path_to_remote_directory
```

is possible using R code? In other words, for copy a file in local machine in R, one could use `file.copy`, what are the R possibilities to copy file from local machine to a remote machine?

Comment: You could always use `system` to make a `scp` call

Comment: @Dason, would you please write an exemplary  command ?

Comment: `system("that thing you wrote goes here")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is package [ssh.utils](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ssh.utils/versions/1.0) which wraps ssh commands in R functions.

So your example would become:

```
library(ssh.utils)
cp.remote(remote.src = "", 
          remote.dest = "username@server_ip", 
          path.src = "localmachine/path_to_the_file",
          path.dest = "path_to_remote_directory")
```

EDIT: I could install it  but anyway it's not very flexible as it does not accept options...

With a system command this would be just:

```
system("scp localmachine/path_to_the_file username@server_ip:/path_to_remote_directory")
```

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ssh.utils’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)`